# Crosstab Query from a Query with a Subquery

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Can anyone help me with a problem I am having with a CrossTab Query to compare current prices from our suppliers?
The select Query that it works from has a sub query that selects on only the most resent prices for our price comparison and this works perfectly for the data we need, see below:

qryPriceComp:

```
SELECT tblPriceComp.SupplyerID, tblPriceComp.ProductID, 
    tblPriceComp.Effdt, tblPriceComp.CostPrice, 
    tblProduct.Product, tblSupplier.Supplier
FROM tblSupplier INNER JOIN 
    (tblProduct INNER JOIN tblPriceComp ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblPriceComp.ProductID) 
    ON tblSupplier.SupplierID = tblPriceComp.SupplyerID
WHERE (((tblPriceComp.Effdt) In 
    (SELECT MAX(B.EffDt) AS MaxOfDt FROM tblPriceComp AS B 
     WHERE tblPriceComp.ProductID=B.ProductID 
       AND tblPriceComp.SupplyerID=B.SupplyerID  
       AND B.EffDt <= Date()+1)));
```

This is then used for the crosstab query 
qryPriceComp_Crosstab:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(qryPriceComp.CostPrice) AS SumOfCostPrice
SELECT qryPriceComp.Product
FROM qryPriceComp
GROUP BY qryPriceComp.Product
ORDER BY qryPriceComp.Product, qryPriceComp.Supplier
PIVOT qryPriceComp.Supplier;
```

But when run it gives an error that both tblPriceComp.ProductID and tblSupplier.SupplierID are invalid. I have tried adding them as perimeters but when run this gives a box to enter the ID numbers which is no good as we want to see all productIDs and SupplyerIDs. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: When the Crosstab query is run I get 
"The Microsoft Access databace engin does not recognize  'tblPriceComp.ProductID' as a valid field name or expressions."
and 
"The Microsoft Access databace engin does not recognize  'tblPriceComp.SupplyerID' as a valid field name or expressions."

Comment: Odd. You can try to remove all fields that are not used in the crosstab query, namely `tblPriceComp.SupplyerID, tblPriceComp.ProductID,     tblPriceComp.Effdt`, from the SELECT list in qryPriceComp.

Comment: If all else fails, you can change qryPriceComp to a `INSERT INTO tempTable` query, and then base the crosstab query on tempTable.

Comment: Greetings Space Cadet, Sorry for the late reply we were chased out of the office so they could lock up. As you said changing to an insert solved the problem. When the crosstab table is wanted I have created a delete query to clear everything from tblPriceCompCrosstab, then run qryPriceComp & insert the results in to tblPriceCompCrosstab, then run the crosstab for the results. Its crazy long-winded and inefficient and will require more regular Compact and Repair on the back end but until I can find a better more optimised way I will have do his. Thank You for your help :)

Comment: Did removing the unused fields change anything?

Comment: Greetings Space Cadet, No, removing the other fields did not work still, I tried changing the subquery to match and that did not work, and the select query failed to run. Crosstab Parameters just don't like Subquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but a usable workaround:

Change `qryPriceComp` to a `INSERT INTO tempTable` query, and then base the crosstab query on `tempTable`.

Before each INSERT run, a `DELETE * FROM tempTable` must be executed.