# Access DB engine does not recognize field when using Crosstab and subquery joins

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, crosstab

I am in MS Access trying to join two queries. The first query is a Crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Q1.Downtime) AS SumOfDowntime 
SELECT Q1.Batch 
FROM [QryDowntime] Q1
GROUP BY Q1.Batch 
PIVOT Q1.Category;
```

This runs, no issues. It is summing downtime for OEE for context. Output looks something like:

```
Batch Availability Performance Quality 
1        0           5           2
2        3           1           5
...
```

I then have a separate query that pulls the date from the previous record:

```
SELECT B2.Batch, 
     (SELECT TOP 1 B1.LastPallet
     FROM TblBatches AS B1 
     WHERE B1.ID < B2.ID
     ORDER BY B1.ID DESC) AS PrevEnd
FROM TblBatches AS B2;
```

Again, no issues. This runs and the output looks something like:

```
Batch   PrevEnd
 1       8/2/2021
 2       8/5/2021
...
```

I have a summary table and want to join these two.

```
SELECT B1.Batch, 
Q1.Availability, 
Q1.Performance, 
Q1.Quality, 
Q2.PrevEnd
FROM (TblBatches AS B1 
LEFT JOIN QryCrosstab AS Q1 ON B1.Batch = Q1.Batch) 
LEFT JOIN QryDate AS Q2 ON B1.Batch = Q2.Batch;
```

I thought this would be the easy part but I get the error "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'B2.ID' as a valid field name or expression." If I remove either of the joins, the query works fine.

I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526344/crosstab-query-from-a-query-with-a-subquery) but, as the author states, it is not really a solution. I do not want to use more tables if there is another way to fix the error.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890288/ms-access-crosstab-query-based-on-a-query-containing-a-subquery) but it is not quite the same. I don't really have a subquery I can do beforehand. If I can, I do not know how to do it. There is nothing dynamic. I am not accepting user inputs. These are straightforward queries. I am hoping there is a strange typo or incorrect syntax.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should edit question to show sample raw data as text tables.

Comment: My experience is cross-tab queries bug and must be replaced with temporary tables when this happens.  So I usually end up completing the entire query with vba behind the scenes of the form or report then I clean up any temporary tables when I close the form or report

Comment: @mazoula - thanks for the reply. In most cases, I could see that working. My issue is I have this integrated with SharePoint and PowerBI. I have PowerBI running the query to get the data to make nice visualizations. It would simplify the entire workstream if the query would just run and be useable. I'm not sure how I'd get PowerBI to run a macro in the Access DB without opening it but that's a question for a different forum...